# Safecracker File Fields only uploads the first one

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads, safecracker-file

I'm trying to use multiple Safecracker File fields in a Safecracker form.

I tried to use one matrix field with one column - the SC File field. On submission, no rows or files were added.

I thought it would be easier to take Matrix out of the equation so I changed it to 3 separate SC File fields. Now only the first field gets uploaded. I don't see any errors (tried logged in as Super Admin and Non-Super Admin)

My template code is very simple.

```
{exp:safecracker ...}
  {custom_fields}
    {if safecracker_file}
      {display_field}
    {/if} 
  {/custom_fields}
{/exp:safecracker}
```

The fields are output correctly, each have unique names.
The following is what is output for each field:

```
<div class="safecracker_file_set">
  <div class="safecracker_file_hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME_3_hidden" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="safecracker_file_placeholder_input">
    <input type="hidden" name="CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME" value="NULL">
  </div>
  <div class="safecracker_file_input">
    <input type="file" name="CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Running 2.5.3, but I don't see anything in the changelog that directly mentions something like this. I'd *realllllly* like to avoid upgrading.

Comment: Do the three Safecracker File fields all have unique names when you inspect the source code of the generated page?

Comment: Yes, they do. I'll update my question to show the code that's generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My custom fields were named as `_x` with underscores:

`{attachment}`, `{attachment_2}`, `{attachment_3}`

Removing the underscores fixed the problem:

`{attachment}`, `{attachment2}`, `{attachment3}`.

This was verified by EllisLab as a bug and a [bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19231) has been filed.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I have a similar setup that is working correctly, but it's on a 2.5.2 install. Code is identical to yours - is it possible there's a js conflict?

Comment: Hmm I don't see any JS errors when loading the page or submitting it.